# MYSQL: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql

I've read many of the questions that talk about this problem but none seem to solve mine.

Basically, i receive the following error:

```
Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

when trying to execute the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Privacy (
    Biography varchar(20),
    BirthDate varchar(20),
    Email varchar(20),
    Location varchar(20),
    RealName varchar(20),
    Sex varchar(6),
    User varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (User),
    FOREIGN KEY (User) REFERENCES Users(Username)
    ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

I thought I couldn't have a primary key and a foreign on the same column, but then I made some searches and found out that it's perfectly fine. Maybe I'm just doing it in the wrong way.

**Edit:**

This is the Users table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users ("
    Avatar varchar(255),
    Biography text,
    Birth_Date date,
    Email varchar(255),
    Location varchar(255),
    Password varchar(20),
    Profile_Views int(11),
    Real_Name varchar(255),
    Reputation int(11),
    Signup_Date datetime,
    Username varchar(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (Username)
) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: what db engine is used for the tables?

Comment: I'm not sure using the username as a primary key would be the thing to do here. I would advice adding an id in your users table (autoincrement) and referencing that. Nothing to do with your error probably btw

Comment: Are both tables INNODB?

Comment: Yes, both tables are InnoDB.

Comment: Having the PK of a table be an FK suggests that the referencing table's columns could simply be appended to the referenced table...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is `ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE` line.

If you use RESTRICT MySQL will be happy.

It makes sense, since you can not make primary key NULL once you delete user from Users table.

*Edit: you can use `ON DELETE CASCADE` as there were pointed out in the comments, then it will **delete** the entire row from Privacy.*

Comment: @eggy Right, I'll add it as a note.

Comment: Well, that would be odd since I've got similar queries that create other tables and they are working...

Comment: Huh. My bad. Case-sensitive naming in *nix

Comment: @ShadowBroker: Are the FKs also PK (which imposes the not `NULL` constraint) in the other tables?  One assumes not, since you originally thought that might be the root of your problem.

Comment: @AlmaDo I think you can change it in mysql settings regardless your OS: variable `lower_case_table_names`

Comment: @vadchen Thank you! That solved my problem. Basically the SET NULL was giving me problems because the FK was also the PK and therefore couldn't be set to null, right? :)

Comment: @ShadowBroker right, it should be either restricted or cascaded (also deleted)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Privacy (
Biography varchar(20),
BirthDate varchar(20),
Email varchar(20),
Location varchar(20),
RealName varchar(20),
Sex varchar(6),
User varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (User),
FOREIGN KEY (User) REFERENCES Users(User)
)
```